# How do I add a button to a fragment?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

How can I add a button to my fragment that makes the main activity switch to a different fragment when you touch it. I looked online for tutorials but they were unclear. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to maintain a callback to MainActivity in your fragment, and have MainActivity implement a method that does the actual switching. What I would do is have an instance variable named `MainActivity mActivityCallback` and then assign it in your fragment's `onCreate()` method by saying `mActivityCallback = (MainActivity)getActivity()`. Then add an `OnClickListener()` to the button that calls `mActivityCallback.switchFragments()`. And in `switchFragments()` you would do whatever you needed with `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransactions` to switch the fragment. As for the second question I have no idea how to do it in Android studio - but in Eclipse ADT you click on the XML layout file and it pops up in the GUI editor.

Comment: you use onclicklistener? I meant the buttons that you add in the layout xml file. how do you use onClickListener for those?

Comment: You can declare buttons through XML but find references to them programatically - using findViewById(). It's probably better if you go follow @The Original Android's link and get the basics of creating an android gui down - because this should cover that. It'll be a lot harder to absorb any info other people give, if you don't have that foundation.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you start with an Android Tutorial. You will learn many answers to your questions on your own. Here is one link from Google, [Building a Simple User Interface](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html). Snippet from tutorial is below. Check the Button element:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
      <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the tutorial, but wasnt actually the problem. The problem was i wasnt sure how to link the button in the xml file to the java code. Would you use view.findVewById(id of the button)? Sorry if this isnt that clear.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You still have to add a Button element onto a Layout file, simply by adding the text or using the GUI editor.

Comment: The tutorial that I listed shows an example of how to "Add a Button". Just try it out and have fun.

Comment: Ya dont get me wrong that was a good tutorial but I kinda already knew how to make a ui like that. I just wasnt completely sure how to reference a button from the xml file in my fragment, but thank you anyway!